# slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in udacity self driving

Tags: python, numpy

in udacity self driving https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car/tree/master/vehicle-detection/u-net the method get_mask_seg(img, bb_boxes_f) gives slice indices must be integers or none or have an **index** method

```
<ipython-input-58-b0cc385c742b> in <module>()
      2 
      3 training_gen = generate_train_batch(df_vehicles,10)
----> 4 batch_img,batch_mask = next(training_gen)

<ipython-input-55-1399e4d6a92a> in generate_train_batch(data, batch_size)
     12                                                    scale_range=50
     13                                                   )
---> 14             img_mask = get_mask_seg(img,bb_boxes)
     15             batch_images[i_batch] = img
     16             batch_masks[i_batch] =img_mask

<ipython-input-51-b5ad142378f0> in get_mask_seg(img, bb_boxes_f)
      8         bb_box_i = [bb_boxes_f.iloc[i]['xmin'],bb_boxes_f.iloc[i]['ymin'],
      9                 bb_boxes_f.iloc[i]['xmax'],bb_boxes_f.iloc[i]['ymax']]
---> 10         img_mask[bb_box_i[1]:bb_box_i[3],bb_box_i[0]:bb_box_i[2]]= 1
     11         img_mask = np.reshape(img_mask,(np.shape(img_mask)[0],np.shape(img_mask)[1],1))
     12     return img_mask

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is breaking due to a relatively recent change in NumPy. To fix it, you'll need to ensure that the index array `bb_box_i` is an integer array. The easiest way to do that is probably to add a line of code that does `bb_box_i = bb_box_i.astype('int')` before indexing into the `img_mask` array.

Answer (score 1):

this code works better

```
img_mask[int(bb_box_i[1]):int(bb_box_i[3]),int(bb_box_i[0]):int(bb_box_i[2])]= 1
```